# Newline character working for console.log() but not chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows

I'm concatenating a bunch of strings from an array together with a new line character after each iteration:

```
booksList = booksList + library.shelves[i].books[j].name + ", " +
   library.shelves[i].books[j].author + '\n';
```

When I console.log() to chrome it works, but when I use jquery to set the text of a div it doesn't. I'm on a windows comp. Any ideas?

I'm using jquery to set booksList to the text of a div:

```
$('#libraryDisplay').text(booksList);
```

Comment: You should use `<br>` in a div.

Comment: What @spaceman said. The console is for writing out data as text. A <div> element is part of the HTML web page and therefore the rendering engine won't know what to do with a new line character.

Comment: <br> gets printed literally. Could it have to do with the fact that I'm using this to set the text of a div:
    $('#libraryDisplay').text(booksList);

Comment: Use `$('#libraryDisplay').html(booksList)` then.

Comment: awesome thanks!! so .text get printed literally and .html reads the html elements?

Comment: Text prints out as text and html is used as html :)

Comment: @spaceman - turn your comments into an answer (with explanation about newlines/whitespace doing nothing in HTML) and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `<br>` for new lines in HTML. Spaces and new lines are used in HTML for formatting of the code and making it human readable and don't do much for markup itself.

And you should also use jquery's `html()` function to insert html to a page, because `text()` acts like `htmlspecialchars` in a way, replacing all the symbols that create html markup with their text variants.

```
booksList = booksList + library.shelves[i].books[j].name + ", " +
                   library.shelves[i].books[j].author + '<br>';

$('#libraryDisplay').html(booksList);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put a style on the div like this:

```
$('#libraryDisplay').css('white-space', 'pre-wrap');
```

Of course `<br>` also works as it was answered before:

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
<br>
```

instead of \n.